# Mongodb list current connection

Tags: mongodb-3.0

I am using a db.currentOp() to check the current connection in Mongodb. 
How can I get the total number of all record and how can I get all the "client" IP in a one column?
Thanks

```
db.currentOp()
{
        "inprog" : [
                {
                        "desc" : "WT RecordStoreThread: local.oplog.rs",
                        "threadId" : "1068",
                        "active" : true,
                        "opid" : 77300,
                        "secs_running" : 712,
                        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(712734301),
                        "op" : "none",
                        "ns" : "local.oplog.rs",
                        "query" : {

                        },
                        "numYields" : 0,
                        "locks" : {

                        },
                        "waitingForLock" : false,
                        "lockStats" : {
                                "Global" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "w" : NumberLong(1)
                                        }
                                },
                                "Database" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "w" : NumberLong(1)
                                        }
                                },
                                "oplog" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "w" : NumberLong(1)
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
            {
                    "desc" : "conn52",
                    "threadId" : "4692",
                    "connectionId" : 52,
                    "client" : "10.10.50.218:60909",
                    "active" : true,
                    "opid" : 101277,
                    "secs_running" : 2,
                    "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(2883686),
                    "op" : "getmore",
                    "ns" : "local.oplog.rs",
                    "query" : {
                            "getMore" : NumberLong("15696192304"),
                            "collection" : "oplog.rs",
                            "maxTimeMS" : NumberLong(5000),
                            "term" : NumberLong(117),
                            "lastKnownCommittedOpTime" : {
                                    "ts" : Timestamp(1501842736, 18),
                                    "t" : NumberLong(117)
                            }
                    },
                    "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN",
                    "numYields" : 0,
                    "locks" : {

                    },
                    "waitingForLock" : false,
                    "lockStats" : {
                            "Global" : {
                                    "acquireCount" : {
                                            "r" : NumberLong(2)
                                    }
                            },
                            "Database" : {
                                    "acquireCount" : {
                                            "r" : NumberLong(1)
                                    }
                            },
                            "oplog" : {
                                    "acquireCount" : {
                                            "r" : NumberLong(1)
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            },
....
...
..
```

Comment: see the 2nd answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945107/is-there-anyway-to-discover-which-ip-addresses-are-connected-to-the-db

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will help to aggregate the information -

**Connection Count by ClientIP, with Total**

For Mongo Shell:

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.reduce((accumulator, connection) => { ipaddress = connection.client ? connection.client.split(":")[0] : "unknown"; accumulator[ipaddress] = (accumulator[ipaddress] || 0) + 1; accumulator["TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT"]++; return accumulator; }, { TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT: 0 })
```

Formatted:

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.reduce(
  (accumulator, connection) => {
    ipaddress = connection.client ? connection.client.split(":")[0] : "unknown";
    accumulator[ipaddress] = (accumulator[ipaddress] || 0) + 1;
    accumulator["TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT"]++;
    return accumulator;
  },
  { TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT: 0 }
)
```

Example Output:

```
{
    "TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT" : 331,
    "192.168.253.72" : 8,
    "192.168.254.42" : 17,
    "127.0.0.1" : 3,
    "192.168.248.66" : 2,
    "11.178.12.244" : 2,
    "unknown" : 41,
    "3.100.12.33" : 86,
    "11.148.23.34" : 168,
    "81.127.34.11" : 1,
    "84.147.25.17" : 3
}
```

(the 192.x.x.x addresses are internal Atlas monitoring)

Comment: What does the unknown mean?

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
db.currentOp().inprog.forEach(function(x) { print(x.client) })
172.16.0.1:42768
172.16.0.4:59984
172.16.0.2:50643
172.16.0.1:20183
```

If you want to remove the port add a regex:

```
db.currentOp().inprog.filter(x => x.ns === 'local.oplog.rs').forEach(function(x) { print(x.client ? x.client.replace(/:.*$/,'') : '-') })
172.16.0.1
172.16.0.4
172.16.0.2
172.16.0.1
```

Comment: can't run currentOp on atlas :(