# List all connections, IP addresses and users in MongoDB 3.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

I'm attempting to create a list of all current connections to my MongoDB 3.2 database.  So far I've been able to list connections using:

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(x) { print(x.client_s) })
```

hacked together from [another answer for MongoDB 2.2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182673/mongodb-list-current-connection) but it's a bit messy:

```
mongos> db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(x) { print(x.client_s) })
10.0.8.37:34572
10.0.8.42:40883
10.0.8.39:37430
10.0.8.39:43980
10.0.8.43:60428
10.0.8.38:37615
10.0.8.39:57476
[unknown type]
10.0.8.37:39592
[unknown type]
[unknown type]
10.0.8.38:44813
10.0.8.41:55001
[unknown type]
[unknown type]
[unknown type]
10.0.8.43:37350
[unknown type]
[unknown type]
[unknown type]
[unknown type]
[unknown type]
[unknown type]
[unknown type]
10.0.8.40:42973
[unknown type]
[unknown type]
[unknown type]
10.0.8.39:57488
[unknown type]
[unknown type]
```

I'd like to filter out the [unknown type] result and then tie each op to a user.  I've noticed username and connectionId pop up in the MongoDB logs, so I can see it's possible — just not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Could you update your O.S Environment?